# How to limiting subquery requests to one?

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I was thinking a way to using one query with a subquery instead of using two seperate queries.

But turns out using a subquery is causing multiple requests for each row in result set. Is there a way to limit that count subquery result only one with in a combined query ?

```
SELECT `ad_general`.`id`, 
    ( SELECT  count(`ad_general`.`id`) AS count 
        FROM (`ad_general`) 
        WHERE `city` = 708 ) AS count, 
  FROM (`ad_general`) 
  WHERE `ad_general`.`city` =  '708' 
  ORDER BY `ad_general`.`id` DESC
  LIMIT 15
```

May be using a join can solve the problem but dunno how ?

Comment: Why is 708 in quotes in one part of the query, but not in the other? Is ad_general.city a string or integer?

Comment: integer but i don't think there isn't any significant difference causing by quotes.

Comment: Note you can [format lines as code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/) by indenting them four spaces. The "{}" button in the editor toolbar does this for you. The greater-than (`>`) is for quoting a block of text from somewhere. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting.

Comment: The SQL statement isn't valid. When you give [sample code](http://sscce.org/), make sure it's representative. Also, without the schema (`CREATE TABLE` statements), the sample is incomplete. For example, `id` columns are usually primary keys, which means any given value occurs at most once in the table. However, the query suggests this isn't the case, but we can't tell if this is a problem with the query, a problem with the table definition, or perfectly valid.

Comment: What is it you REALLY want... just a single count per the one city???  Or do you want a single count for ALL cities, but group the counts PER city? (yet you have the filter on city = 708 (indicating only one)?

Comment: @outis you've got my upvote for informing me :) yes query is not working because it's not the actual query it's a simplified version of my original query and i've changed names of columns to english, therefore i can't include an example table structure.

Comment: @DRapp may be you should take a look to accepted answer

Comment: @outis i appreciated your effort to teach me the basics of stackoverflow but i think you are missing the important point: what the question is about. can you explain me how the table structure is going to help while answering the question ?

Comment: @motto: you can include a simplified schema, just as you include a simplified `SELECT`. That's not the basics of SO, that's the basics of how to ask a question so it can be answered (http://sscce.org/, linked in a previous, explains in more detail, as does ["Writing the Perfect Question"](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints)). Without the schema, we can only guess at how to correctly use a self-join to give the desired results, as the schema will determine the proper grouping.

Comment: Also, reading the accepted answer shouldn't be required to understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ad_general.id, stats.cnt
FROM ad_general
  JOIN (
      SELECT count(*) as cnt
        FROM ad_general
        WHERE city = 708
    ) AS stats
WHERE ad_general.city = 708
ORDER BY ad_general.id DESC
LIMIT 15;
```

The explicit table names aren't required, but are used both for clarity and maintainability (the explicit table names will prevent any imbiguities should the schema for `ad_general` or the generated table ever change).

Comment: thanks a ton!, that's what i was looking for. and it's definitely faster than first query.

Comment: i think outis has edited for an unknown reason your answer and edited version is not working.

Comment: @motto, I do not see an error. it seems to be the same just more explicit and more characters to type. I do not share his view on the formatting, but would not start a war of edits =)

Answer (score 0):

You can self-join (join the table to itself table) and apply aggregate function to the second.

```
SELECT `adgen`.`id`, COUNT(`adgen_count`.`id`) AS `count`
  FROM `ad_general` AS `adgen`
    JOIN `ad_general` AS `adgen_count` ON `adgen_count`.city = 708
  WHERE `adgen`.`city` = 708
  GROUP BY `adgen`.`id`
  ORDER BY `adgen`.`id` DESC
  LIMIT 15
```

However, it's impossible to say what the appropriate grouping is without knowing the structure of the table.

Comment: @motto: it doesn't work because you haven't given us enough information to write a working query. Read over the documents I've linked to previously and update your question.